# Internal Error: libxenlight failed to create new domain "FreeBSD-13.2"

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, arm, libvirt, xen

I tried to use xen as a hypervisor instead of kvm + libvirt + virt-manager to boot FreeBSD on my ARM Chromebook where I have installed Devuan 5,since Stefano said :

```
Libvirt + virt-manager with the xen accelerator might work on the ARM Chromebook. 
That's because as far as I know Xen integration in libvirt is done via linking to 
libxl directly and libxl is supported and working on ARM.
```

Unfortunately something is not working properly. What I did has been to reboot the machine in xen,enable libvirtd & and virtlogd & and virt-manager &,but this is what happened :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.17/bin/pygrub", line 884, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find partition containing kernel")
RuntimeError: Unable to find partition containing kernel
```

I think it does not recognize the FreeBSD file system structure and its kernel. Libvirt seems to have been programmed to boot Linux,not FreeBSD.  In Fact,I did the counterproof.

According with this post :

https://blog.roberthallam.org/2020/05/solving-unable-to-find-partition-containing-kernel/

I've created a file called menu.lst inside the boot directory of the image file called "debian.img",adding the following content inside :

```
default 0
timeout 10 
title Debian 
root (hd0,1) 
kernel /boot/vmlinux-6.1.59-stb-xen-cbe+ root=/dev/xvda
initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.1.59-stb-xen-cbe+
```

and I tried again to boot the image using virt-manager. It gave this error again :

```
error :libxlDomainStartPerform:1256 : internal error : 
libxenlight failed to create new domain 'debian12'
```

but giving a look inside the log file and I found this interesting situation ;

```
Using <class 'grub.GrubConf.GrubConfigFile'> to parse /boot/grub/menu.lst
(B )0 [1;24r [m [?7h [?1h = [H [J [?1h = [1B    pyGRUB  version 0.6
[1B [0m
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
[1B [0m x [0;7m Debian 12
          [m [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m x [72C [0m x
[1B [0m
mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
[1B [70D [0m Use the ↑ and ↓ keys to select which entry is highlighted. [1B
[58DPress enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the [1B [52Dcommands
before booting, 'a' to modify the kernel arguments [1B [59Dbefore booting,
or 'c' for a command line. [12A [26C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in
10 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  9 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  8 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  7 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  6 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  5 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  4 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  3 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  2 seconds [?1h =
[J [17A [73C [17B [68DWill boot selected entry in  1 seconds [?1l > 
[24;1H [?1l >
```

so,it seems that it tried to boot,but for an unknown reason,it still gives the error.

Anyway : My xen setup is not broken anymore ; Using Libvirt Linux seems to be able to boot,FreeBSD does not.